# Field Calculate to remove certain values in field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a field named "ZIP" which has the zip code information for numerous records. Some of them have 9 numbers, but I only want them to have the first 5. What should my Pre-Logic Script look like to Field Calculate removing the last 4 numbers in this field?

Here is an image of the Field Calculator and the field:

[image]

Comment: In python you can use the simple expression: !ZIP![0:4]. No code block necessary.

Comment: I agree, but this is giving me a geoprocessing error.

Comment: Got your radio button switched to Python? Also, don't include that period after the ].

Comment: Yes and I did not include the period.

Comment: Is ZIP a field alias by chance? Or conversely, you might disable your code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If the field is numeric**, Python expression:

```
!zip![:4]
```

will fail.

It is easier to use vb script option:

```
left([zip],5)
```

This will populate output field of numeric and text type.

Comment: That's it! It is not a string, so that python expression does not work. Thanks!

Comment: It will work with some modification, e.g. if output field is numeric it's going to be float(str(!ZIP)[:4])

Answer (score 4):

Use the string indices.  Instead of creating a whole function, just do something like:

`!ZIP![:5]` --> basically grab everything from 0 index up to but not including the 5th index.

So it only grabs the indices 0,1,2,3,4.

Check out [this tutorial](http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) for more information.

If there are more than 5 it will just grab the first 5.  If there are 5 exact, it will grab them.

Comment: in the field calculator it'll probably be something like `!ZIP![:5]` I think